# Groovy filter two dimensions array

Tags: arrays, groovy, findall

```
​def a = [[6, 4], [8, 6], [5, 3]]

a.findAll {
   it.findAll {
      it != 4 && it != 6 
   }
}​​
```

So I have this pseudo code written so I wouldn't need to write my complex code. So I want to remove all the 4's from the array but if I write only `it != 4`
then it doesn't remove it, if I write both of the numbers as I wrote now it != 4 && it != 6 then it removes it. Should I use it somehow differently? I want this array

```
def a = [[6, 4], [8, 6], [5, 3]]
```

To remove all number 4's from it for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to modify the collection you need to use `collect` instead of `findAll`:

```
def a =  [
    [6, 4],
    [8, 6],
    [5, 3],
  ]

assert a.collect { l -> l.findAll { it != 4 } } == [[6], [8, 6], [5, 3]]
```

Comment: @Opal: ahh you precede me! :) What do you think about ``collect`` vs ``each``. Are they processed in a different way internally?

Comment: @GiuseppeRicupero in your answer the original list will be modified, `collect` returns new one. Basically that's. `each` is rather for iterating, `collect` for processing.

Answer (score 4):

**Remove sublist with `4` inside**

Use the `in` syntax to check inside the sublist. So your code can be rewritten as:

```
def a = [[6,4],[8,6],[5,3]] 
assert  [[8, 6], [5, 3]] == a.findAll { !(4 in it) }
```

**Remove  `4` from every sublist**

```
def a = [[6,4],[8,6],[5,3]] 
// Modify list in place, to return a new list use collect
assert  [[6], [8, 6], [5, 3]] == a.each{ it.removeAll { it == 4 } }
```

Comment: I want the result to look like
[[6],[8,6],[5,3]] 

So it would remove the 4. Is this not possible?